# How to stop javascript ++ or - - condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have 2 functions as below for a multiple-step configuration in a webpage.

```
protected clickNext(event:any, config:any) : any{
    this.activeIndex++;
}

protected clickPrev(event:any, config:any) : any{
    this.activeIndex--;
}
```

buttons:

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
        <!-- <a class="btn" style="color: white" [disabled]="disabled"> Previous </a> -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn" style="color: white" [disabled]="prevBtn_disabled" (click)="clickPrev($event, _finalConfig)">Prev</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" style="color: white" [disabled]="nextBtn_disabled" (click)="clickNext($event, _finalConfig)">Next</button>
    </div>
```

When I click next button `clickNext` will trigger and when i click prev button `clickPrev` will be triggered. activeIndex is a variable pass into the html to determine which step to activate. Thats the whole idea. As you can see am getting `config` which is an array. What i need to achieve is once i reach the last step or the last object in the array, i dont need to do the ++ same for if am at the first object and click prev. Shouldnt do the --. Sorry am actually bit new to Javascript. How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Should I use any looping and if else conditions? i have tried if else, but somehow the value is getting overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether `this.activeIndex` is already equal to the index of the first or last item in the `config` array:

```
protected clickNext(event:any, config:any) : any{
    if (this.activeIndex < config.length - 1) {
        this.activeIndex++;
    }
}

protected clickPrev(event:any, config:any) : any{
    if (this.activeIndex > 0) {
        this.activeIndex--;
    }
}
```

It would be good to also disable your *Next* or *Prev* buttons if already at the last or first step so that the user has some indication that they're at one end or the other. (But I can't tell you how to do that because you don't show your buttons.)

Comment: yes i have a variable for both disabling next and previous buttons. Can guide me nnnnn how to do that?

Comment: Can i do it in this functions itself?

Comment: for next i can use array.length with the index, but for the prev how to do that?

Comment: I hard core length with 0?

Comment: It should be possible from within those two functions, but I did already say I can't tell you how because you didn't show your buttons. It's not clear how those functions are called, either: normally in an event handler `this` would be a reference to the element on which the event occurred, but that doesn't seem to be the case in your code because if it was then you would have two separate `activeIndex` properties, one per button.

Comment: About hardcoding 0, yes, the first item in an array is at index 0, which is why the code I showed tests against 0 in the `clickPrev()` function. The last item in an array is at index `.length - 1`...

Comment: HI nnnn updated with button code. Its actually an angular2 project. but the idea is the same as any JS code

Comment: `protected clickNext(event:any, config:any) : any{
        let arrLen: any = config.length-1;
        if (this.activeIndex < config.length -1) {
            this.activeIndex++;
            console.log(this.activeIndex);
        }
        if (this.activeIndex == arrLen){
            this.nextBtn_disabled = true;
            this.prevBtn_disabled = false;
        }
    }`

Comment: Did something like this. But not sure its the best approach or not

Comment: I don't know Angular, so I might be *really* wrong about how you should do it, but that seems about right in that you seem to be updating properties of your model that are referenced in the view.

Comment: @blackdaemon: It's just a simple logic - there should not be any other work-around which is considered as ***right practice***. The logic is just simple that you need a ***condition*** here to check if it need to run the increment or decrement. So the ***condition*** here ***surely*** need to access the involved array - more specifically the array size info - How could you know if the current index is out of range of the some array without knowing its size (length)? This logic is just basic in programming, it's just the ***only*** practice, not any other *righter* one.

Comment: @Hopeless - In that comment I think the OP was talking about the part to cause the button to be disabled and whether that's how to do that part in Angular.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't think so. He said this `Did something like this. But not sure its the best approach or not` - In fact he did not even say that it works or not? Just wondering about if it's the ***best*** approach. And per the original requirement, the code he adjusted there seems to be ok now. (in fact the array here is `config`, but in your answer you thought it was `any` - which should be some type in Angular). I also don't know angular but I'm sure the OP should be able to code in Angular, he just wonders about the ***best*** logic/idea.

Comment: @Hopeless - Oops, that was a typo, I knew `:any` was the Typescript type, but just absentmindedly typed the wrong thing. I have fixed that in my answer. I still think in the comment OP was asking about the disabling with Angular, because that was an extra requirement prompted by the comment at the end of my answer, and they basically took the code from my answer and then added the extra bit to set the button disabled properties.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, the adjusted code was made from your idea. So he should get what he wants now (as per the question title). But still he may not know about how to change the corresponding variables (which are bound with `[disabled]` of each button). Well I think an Angular JS programmer/coder should know how to do this easily (it's just some kind of simple thing).